# Meta-Analysis: Summarizing several effects of a study

Tags: r, mixed-model, meta-analysis, metafor, forest-plot

I am currently conducting a meta-analysis looking at a rather global effect. Therefore, some of the included studies report several effects which can be included. As far as I read in the literature, it is most common to take an average of the reported effects per study to not introduce a bias. In some cases the effects cancel out, but it seems somehow wrong to just report a "null"-effect, as it might be quite interesting to see in which cases the effects are negative and in which they are positive.
Is it somehow possible to include all the effects measured within a single group, or at least display all "subeffects" in a forest plot?

At the moment, I am using the metafor package in R, using a random-effects model.

Thanks a lot to anyone reading and thinking about this!

Comment: I suggest using `rma.mv` and specifying the study as a random effect, for example with `random = ~1|study`. The [documentation](https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/rma.mv.html) goes into more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I had a closer look at the specifications, but if I understood correctly it would assume the same "true effect" for each of the included studies, which is clearly not the case as they are looking at different subeffects within a single study . Would it make sense to define a list of random effects so that `random = list(~ 1 | study_id, ~ 1 | subeffect)) `, so I assume the effects measured by each study are not exactly the same, as well as the subeffects  ?

Comment: Have a look at the examples in http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses under multivariate/multi-level.  It might also be worth looking at https://wviechtb.github.io/R-sig-meta-analysis/ which contains links to posts on the mailing list for meta-analysis in R one of which might fit your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the note! The samples truly contributed a lot to my understanding!

Comment: With the random effects, you specify groups that are not independent. If you have multiple estimates from the same study (or two interventions compared to the same control group, for example), you'd specify `random = ~1|study`. If you have more nested levels of dependence, you could add those as random effects. If you found an adequate solution, please add it as an answer to this question (you can answer your own questions).

Comment: As @mdewey suggested, please take a look at the metafor website and especially these examples: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011 and https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:crede2010 and the "A Common Mistake" section. Indeed, you want at the very least `~ 1 | study_id/subeffect`. If multiple effect sizes are measured on the same units, then this is still not quite sufficient due to dependency in the sampling errors. You also want to take a look at https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/misc-recs.html and the "General Workflow" section.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies! I had again a closer look and currently settled for the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hints in the comments, I came to the following solution:

I included all extracted effects in the model.
I used the  `vcalc(..)` function to approximate the var-cov matrix of dependent estimates, and used the `rma.mv(..)` with `random = ~ 1 | study_id/subeffect` to account for the random effect of each study and each subeffect.
Finally I used the `robust(..)` method for cluster-robust estimate of the variance-covariance matrix.

Very helpful for understanding were the [Credé](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:crede2010) example and the [general workflow recommendations](https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/misc-recs.html#general-workflow-for-meta-analyses-involving-complex-dependency-structures) (both from the metafor website) .

Comment: Please accept your own answer if you're no longer waiting for other answer so that the question is labelled answered.